# Merge fields in a file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, bioinformatics

I have a file with 7 columns, a GFF file having chromosomal regions.I want to collapse the rows where REGION ="exon" to only one row in the file.The row has to be collapsed on the basis of regions being overlapping with each other.

```
REGION  START   END  SCORE STRAND FRAME     ATTRIBUTE
 exon   26453   26644   .   +   .   Transcript "XM_092971"; Name "XM_092971"
 exon   26842   27020   .   +   .   Transcript "XM_092971"; Name "XM_092971"
 exon   30355   30899   .   -   .   Transcript "XM_104663"; Name "XM_104663"
 GS_TRAN    30355   34083   .   -   .   GS_TRAN "Hs22_30444_28_1_1"; Name "Hs22_30444_28_1_1"
 snp    30847   30847   .   +   .   SNP "rs2971719"; Name "rs2971719"
 exon   31012   31409   .   -   .   Transcript "XM_104663"; Name "XM_104663"
 exon   34013   34083   .   -   .   Transcript "XM_104663"; Name "XM_104663"
 exon   40932   41071   .   +   .   Transcript "XM_092971"; Name "XM_092971"
 snp    44269   44269   .   +   .   SNP "rs2873227"; Name "rs2873227"
 snp    45723   45723   .   +   .   SNP "rs2227095"; Name "rs2227095"
 exon   134031  134495  .   -   .   Transcript "XM_086913"; Name "XM_086913"            
 exon   134034  134457  .   -   .   Transcript "XM_086914"; Name "XM_086914"
```

Looking at the sample data above,only the last two rows can be merged into one row.So,the new row will become.

```
exon    134031  134495  .   -   .   Transcript "XM_086913"; Name "XM_086913"
```

In case,the end of the other row would have been greater than its previous,that would be the END region in that case.Basically,if there is any overlap,then take the region which starts Earlier,and the one which ends later.

There can be multiple rows of such instance,here only last 2 rows are there.One thing is that the ATRRIBUTE column will definitely show different Transcript names for such rows,which are mostly same in other cases.

Any suggestions on how to proceed.

UPDATED EXAMPLE: If the last 2 rows are like this

```
  exon  134031  134457  .   -   .   Transcript "XM_086913"; Name "XM_086913"            
  exon  134034  134495  .   -   .   Transcript "XM_086914"; Name "XM_086914"
```

Then the Output should be :

```
exon    134031  134495  .   -   .   Transcript "XM_086913"; Transcript "XM_086914"
```

Basically the START from first and END from second.Since I want to cover the overlap in one row only,instead of 2 or 3 or more rows.Here the overlap is between 2 rows, but could be between more than 2 rows as well.

**UPDATED EXAMPLE** (3/24/2014)

```
chr1    HAVANA  stop_codon  1120520 1120522 .   +   0   gene_id "ENSG00000162571.9"; transcript_id "ENST00000379288.3"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "TTLL10"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "TTLL10-001"; level 2; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS8.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000851.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002420.2";
chr1    HAVANA  UTR 1115077 1115233 .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000162571.9"; transcript_id "ENST00000379288.3"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "TTLL10"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "TTLL10-001"; level 2; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS8.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000851.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002420.2";
chr1    HAVANA  UTR 1115414 1115433 .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000162571.9"; transcript_id "ENST00000379288.3"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "TTLL10"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "TTLL10-001"; level 2; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS8.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000851.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002420.2";
chr1    HAVANA  UTR 1120520 1121244 .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000162571.9"; transcript_id "ENST00000379288.3"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "TTLL10"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "TTLL10-001"; level 2; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS8.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000851.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002420.2";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  1115864 1119307 .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000162571.9"; transcript_id "ENST00000460998.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "TTLL10"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "TTLL10-004"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000851.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002423.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    1115864 1116240 .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000162571.9"; transcript_id "ENST00000460998.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "TTLL10"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "TTLL10-004"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000851.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002423.1";
chr1    HAVANA  *exon   1117121 1117195*    .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000162571.9"; transcript_id "ENST00000460998.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "TTLL10"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "TTLL10-004"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000851.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002423.1";
chr1    HAVANA  *exon   1117150 1117826*    .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000162571.9"; transcript_id "ENST00000460998.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "TTLL10"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "TTLL10-004"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000851.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002423.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    1118256 1118427 .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000162571.9"; transcript_id "ENST00000460998.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "TTLL10"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "TTLL10-004"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000851.3"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002423.1";

chr1    HAVANA  transcript  1190648 1209229 .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    1209046 1209229 .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    1203113 1203372 .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
chr1    HAVANA  CDS 1203241 1203372 .   -   0   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
chr1    HAVANA  start_codon 1203370 1203372 .   -   0   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
chr1    HAVANA  stop_codon  1203238 1203240 .   -   0   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    1198726 1198766 .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    1192588 1192690 .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    1192372 1192510 .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
chr1    HAVANA  *exon   1191425 1191505*    .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
chr1    HAVANA  *exon   1190648 1191470*    .   -   .   gene_id "ENSG00000160087.16"; transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; transcript_type "nonsense_mediated_decay"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "UBE2J2-003"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001911.7"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000005432.2";
```

The upper portion shows the overlap in "+" strand,and the below portion shows the overlap in "-" strand.The "-" strand has decreasing regions,so overlap will be like shown in the last 2 rows.Both are different genes.So overlap has to be per gene,as sometimes different genes have overlapping exons also but this is very rare as I have read in some posts.
The gene information can be extracted from the last column,present as"gene_name".

The two rows from gene_name=TTLL10 have overlapping exons,so they will be merged, in the final output.

```
chr1    HAVANA  *exon   1117121 1117195*    .   +   .   transcript_id "ENST00000460998.1"; gene_name "TTLL10"; 
chr1    HAVANA  *exon   1117150 1117826*    .   +   .   transcript_id "ENST00000460998.1"; gene_name "TTLL10";
```

The two rows from gene_name= UBE2J2 have overlap exons.

```
 chr1   HAVANA  *exon   1191425 1191505*    .   -   .   transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; 
  chr1  HAVANA  *exon   1190648 1191470*    .   -   .   transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1";  gene_name "UBE2J2";
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

The rest of the rows remain same,and the above rows get merged for each gene.

```
chr1    HAVANA  *exon   1117121 1117826*    .   +   .   transcript_id "ENST00000460998.1"; gene_name "TTLL10";
chr1    HAVANA  *exon   1190648 1191505*    .   -   .   transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1";  gene_name "UBE2J2";
```

In case,the transcript_ids are different,both transcript id's would be printed although gene_name will remain same.for e.g If for gene,the transcript id's were different like below:

```
  chr1  HAVANA  *exon   1191425 1191505*    .   -   .   transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; gene_name "UBE2J2"; 
  chr1  HAVANA  *exon   1190648 1191470*    .   -   .   transcript_id "ENST00000473215.2";  gene_name "UBE2J2";
```

This will merge to as above,but should have both transcript names.Since,I believe it might be needed and will be important later on to preserve the transcript information.

```
  chr1  HAVANA  *exon   1190648 1191505*    .   -   .   transcript_id "ENST00000473215.1"; "ENST00000473215.2"  gene_name "UBE2J2";
```

Comment: What about elements that overlap but on the other strand? What about [nested genes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_gene#Genes_nested_opposite_coding_sequences)? Also, the [standard GFF format](http://www.sequenceontology.org/gff3.shtml) has `\t` separating the fields. This is not a normal GFF file and will not be read correctly by software expecting true GFF. In short, please clarify what you are attempting to do, this is more than a simple text parsing problem, there are biological considerations as well.

Comment: Thats a very valid point.I am trying to count the RNA sequencing reads that fall in exons,since those are counted twice in case the exons overlap, I want to make only one exon out of an overlap so that the read is counted once.I cut out the first two columns for a Sample GFF file here,But the other columns are from a GFF file.I did not want to complicate things for non-biological background people,so wanted to be as simple as I could.I can provide more information if required.

Comment: And can you be relatively sure you will never have things that overlap on the opposite strand? Can we safely ignore the strand information? Also, how big is this file? Is a solution that reads the whole thing into memory acceptable?

Comment: One more thing, is the first field in the real file a gene name perhaps or is it a chromosome or other large region? Meaning, will each set of overlapping exons have the same first field?

Comment: Yes,each set of overlapping exons should belong to the same gene.Since later on I would look at genes after counting reads in the overlapping eons.

Comment: That makes everything _much_ simpler. It means we can use the gene name to anchor the ranges we are interested in. Please [edit] your question and include an example of the actual file format you need to work with. Also remove the header unless you actually have that in your file.

Comment: I have included an example of the actual file.

Comment: Ah, better! And do you want _all_ the attributes to be copied or only the `gene_name`. By the way, I hope you understand why you should always post your real file. 2 users have already wasted their time giving you answer that will not work on your data (but will on your example) because of format differences.

Comment: Yeah,even I had to think that overlapping exons should be per gene.I want transcript_id and gene_name,Since overlapping exons might be from different transcripts.

Comment: So can you provide a sample of the output with that revised input?

Comment: I provided the Sample Output as well.

Answer (score 6):

An 'awk' approach,

```
awk '
  $1!="exon" {                       # If the first died is unequal to "exon"
    if(previous)print previous       # If there is a previous line then print it
    print                            # Print the current line
    previous=start=end=exon_seq=""   # Set all variable to an empty string
    next                             # Move on to the next line in the input file
  }
  {
    if(exon_seq) {                   # if there is a sequence of lines with "exon in field 1
      if(start<=$2 && end>=$3)       # if the start value (field 2) of the previous line 
                                     # is less or equal to the current line and the end
                                     # value of the previous line is greater than or
                                     # equal to field 3 of the current line
        next                         # then do nothing and read the next line
      else                           # if there is no overlap,
        print previous               # then print the previous line
    }
    else {                           # if we are not already in the a sequence of 
                                     # "exon" lines, then this is the first one
      exon_seq=1                     # so exon_seq should become 1
    }
    previous=$0; start=$2; end=$3    # `start` become field2, `end` becomes field 3 and
                                     # `previous` becomes the current record (line)
  }
  END{                               # After all lines are processed
    if(previous) print previous      # If there still is a previous line, then print it
  }
' file
```

Comment: What are p,b,e,r,x in the script?

Comment: @Ron, you're right, changed the letters to a bit more mnemonic variable names..

Comment: I ran the script but its producing the same input file as its output.

Comment: @Ron Is your file TAB separated? Otherwise, try leaving out `-F'\t'` In fact, it is not required here, I removed it from the script, could you try again?

Comment: Works after removing -F '\t'. Can you explain the code?

Comment: If I interchange the END of the last two rows,it does not work then.It should give me the Start thats earlier and the End which is later between the two rows,but it does not do anything then.

Comment: @Ron, yes there was bug that was corrected I think, plus I printed an explanation..

Comment: @Scrutinizer Good Job!!!

Comment: @Scrutinizer is `getline` and `next` do same thing ?

Comment: @RahulPatil: Thanks :) No `next` is not the same, it simply means abandon all processing of the current line (record) and start with the next one. It continues the next iteration in `awk`'s middle section...

Comment: I have a doubt which line does the script takes this into consideration: To take Start from a different row  and End from a different row, if the start from one row is earlier and a different row has a greater end.

Comment: @Scrutinizer The new code does not work in case the ends are interchanged,it only works when an individual row has both the Least Start and Greatest End.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Perl to solve such a complicated task. Here is a partial solution, you might need to tweak it to suit you better:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw{ max };

sub output {
    my $previous = shift;
    print join ' ', 'exon',
               @{$previous}{qw(start end score strand frame attribute)};
}

$\ = "\n";
my %previous;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($region, $start, $end, $score, $strand, $frame, $attribute)
        = split ' ', $_, 7;

    if ($. == 1) {
        print;

    } elsif ('exon' eq $region) {
        if (keys %previous
            and $start < $previous{end}                # Overlap.
           ) {

            if ($end > $previous{end}) {               # Not contained.
                $previous{attribute} =~ s/; Name .*//;
                $previous{attribute} .= '; ' 
                                     . ($attribute =~ /(Transcript ".*?")/)[0];
                $previous{end} = $end;
            }

        } else {
            if (keys %previous) {
                output(\%previous);
            }

            %previous = ( start     => $start,
                          end       => $end,
                          score     => $score,
                          strand    => $strand,
                          frame     => $frame,
                          attribute => $attribute,
                        );
        }

    } else {
        output(\%previous) if keys %previous;
        %previous = ();
    }
}

output(\%previous) if keys %previous;
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code a little bit?

Comment: You keep the last line in `%previous` if it is an exon. If the current line is an exon, too, you compare their intervals and forget the previous one if it is part of the current one.

Comment: So it chooses the START whichever is earlier and END whichever is the later among "exon" rows?As the last 2 rows where the exons have to be merged could have interchanged ends,In that case START and END would be from different rows.Also Too many if-elses have made a bit too complicated to understand.

Comment: @Ron: I probably do not fully understand the specification. If the END came from the second row, where would the attribute come from?

Comment: so if you compare the starts from both rows,134031 starts earlier so I want that.And end is 134495 so,in this case this row should be the only row I want,but if the end would have been 134457 for this row and the other row had its end as 134495.Then Start of the first and end of the second row.

Comment: Please see the updates I added in the question.

Comment: @Ron: Updated the answer according to the new spec.

Comment: In the subroutine, @{$previous}{qw(start end score strand frame attribute)};                                                   Is {qw(..) the keys of hash %previous? So basically,using hash of arrays in the subroutine??

Comment: @Ron: It's called a "hash slice".

Comment: how is it different from hash of arrays ?

Comment: @Ron: Hash of arrays is a nested structure. Hash slice is just a list of hash values corresponding to a list of keys.

Comment: So,list of values is basically an array which corresponds to a key?

Comment: @Ron: No. Only a scalar corresponds to a key. And, in Perl, a list and an array are different things.

Comment: Okay! the overlap exons if present gets printed out from the subroutine call thats in the end,correct?

Comment: @Ron: The last call prints the last line. The script does not work with your latest sample input, though, as the format has changed significantly.

Comment: So the overlapping exons print from the first "else" statement?,since the second else statement prints the non-exon regions.